# Java - how to return a null in this String method?

Tags: java, arrays, object, null, return

How to make this string return a null if we put `things = null`

```
public class Test {
static String concatAll(Object[] things) {

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
       result.append( things[i] );
    }
    String x = result.toString();
    return x;

}


public static void main(String [] args)
{


    Object[] obj = {19, "abc", " ", 3.5};
    System.out.println(concatAll(obj)); 
}
```

}

this code will print

19abc 3.5

when i put `obj = null` in the main method  this code is not working, Why?

Comment: You should understand what a `NullPointerException` is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception

Comment: "this code is not working" doesn't tell us what you expected or what the result was... or where you set `obj` to null.

Comment: so i want null as a return @JonSkeet , i set obj = null in main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
    static String concatAll(Object[] things) {
      if(null == things) {
        return null;
      }
     //Rest of the code goes here
    }
```

Comment: @Arief27: Please accept the answer, if you think it has helped you. Read this to understand how accepting the answer works. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Your code as it stands try's to index into the `Object` array without checking for null with the code `things.length`, which will throw a `NullPointerException` because there is no array object in existence, so the length field also does not exist.

To fix this use an if statement!

```
static String concatAll(Object[] things) {
if(things == null) {
    return null;
}
...continue code....
```

This will first check `things` for a null  value BEFORE executing code that could throw an exception.

Comment: The NPE will be thrown by `things.length` before `things[i]`.

Comment: @arshajii Fixing that now. Nice Catch.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a method on a null object causes a `NullPointerException`.

In your case if obj = null, then when you call concatAll, things will be null as well. You then try and call things.length which is not valid on a null object.

You can make this method safer by checking the input of strings first. What you want to do exactly will depend on your situation, but here is one example.

```
static String concatAll(Object[] things) {

    if (things == null)
    {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
       result.append( things[i] );
    }
    String x = result.toString();
    return x;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(null!=things)
    {
     for (int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
           result.append( things[i] );
        }
        String x = result.toString();
        return x;
    }else {
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution in addition to posting a code block?

Answer (score 0):

I'd check to make sure that the array wasn't null before using it:

```
public class Test {

    static String concatAll(Object[] things) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        if (things != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
                result.append( things[i] );
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Object[] obj = {19, "abc", " ", 3.5};
        System.out.println(concatAll(obj)); 
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend that you pay attention to formatting.  Style matters.